# android studio design editor is unavailable unit a success build

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

XML not display . Help me please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update Google Repository Version and Google Play Services